# Selecting the unique list in hibernate

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I need to query the table in hibernate with latest records from the table. Table contains multiple versions of the file link to the terminal Id. e.g.

[image]

teminal_info_id is the foreign key to the terminals table. In the above picture I need the list of all the terminals with latest versions e.g.

1 3.0

3 2.0

4 6.0

This is what I tried but its not working.

```
hql.append(" select distinct e.terminals.terminalId from TerminalFiles e");
            hql.append(" order by e.id desc ");
```

Comment: Clarification: would version ordering by string be correct? Or there is a possibility of two or more digits either left or right of the dot?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis yeah its possible that there are more digits on both side and its a string.